# How to integrate a JQuery video player?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, video, media-player

All i want to do is on my site be able to click on an image which pops up a video player which plays an .mp4 file?

I have been searching and found some but i cant seem to get them to play my file?

What is the best jquery player to do this and how?

i think the players cant find the file i have on the server. is it a particular way i have to have it placed?

Comment: you looking for a flash or html5 solution?

Comment: whichever is the best and easiest to integrate

Comment: are you hosting the file... or uploading it to youtube/vimeo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check http://videojs.com/. It has a jquery Plugin.

In modern HTML you could simply use the  Tag for this, the Rest is done by the browser, but there are some limitations caused by the video codec and waht browser supports which video codec. The videojs Plugin seems to have Fallback solutions for these problems.

Comment: when i replace http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4 with http://example.co.uk/v.mp4

Comment: Hm, I assume you read http://videojs.com/#adding-videojs . What happens, when you post the URL from the video directly into the browser addressbar. Can you reach it?

Comment: 404 means, that the file is not where you think it should be. I downloaded the videojs sample (Videojs Startpage, big green button). Then i downloaded some test .mp4 (google gave me this: http://www.gamefront.com/files/16994027/Quality-Sample.mp4/). Then replaced videojs sample file with my file, all in the same directory, with relative URL. Uploaded it to my server. Works like a charm.

Comment: 404 means file not found. So the file is not there. The server blocking things would be another error code.

Comment: i dont get 404 if i type in the url, i get a blank page with a play button but nothing plays

Comment: Have you tried another video? Maybe the file is broken and you need to reencode it? You can try the video from above. Its a 33MB file, works under firefox and chrome perfectly

Comment: you are right there is something wrong with the file. think it may be becoz i converted it from mov to mp4 mayb

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with Flowplayer. It shows a Flash or HTML 5 player (depending on the user's hardware & browser) and its Javascript API is about the best I've found, after trying a few other offerings. It now integrates with online video platforms as well, so it's scalable if your project grows to where that is needed.

Comment: does this only play .flv files or will it play .mov and .mp4?